# Mobile Site Prevent Elastic Page Scrolling

Tags: javascript, android, ipad, mobile, touch

I have developed an ajax site that has a fixed header and footer and a scrollable div in the middle that contains the content of the application.  The site works great on mobile devices as well (iPad, Android, etc) except for the fact that when the user gets to the bottom of the middle scrollable div, the elastic scroll comes into play and the bottom of the page pulls away from the bottom of the screen.  Same when they reach to top of the scrollable div.

I know you can completely prevent elastic scrolling by doing the following:

```
$('#Platform').bind('touchmove', function (e) {    
   e.preventDefault();    
});
```

But this obviously prevents any scrolling at all and then the user can't see the content of the application.  My thought is to put some conditional logic in the above event to make it so that e.preventDefault() is called only when the user is at the top of the div AND they are trying to scroll up or they are at the bottom of the div AND they are trying to scroll down.  I started doing something like this:

```
$('#Platform').bind('touchmove', function (e) {
    var platform = $('#Platform');
    if ((platform.scrollTop() + platform.innerHeight()) >= platform[0].scrollHeight) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

The above code basically determines if they are at the bottom of the scrollable div and if they are, e.preventDefault() is called.  This is great but once they hit the bottom of the div, they will never be able to scroll again!  I figure that I have to somehow determine which way the user is swiping and include that in my logic.  If they are at the bottom and are swiping down, don't scroll.  But if they are at the bottom and swiping up, allow them to scroll.  And visa versa for when they are at the top of the div.

Is this the best way to go about accomplishing my goal?  Is there a better way?  If this is what I should do, how does one determine the direction of the swipe?

Also, is there an easier way to test a website on an iPad, iPhone, Android device than having to deploy it to a development server?  I would have played around with my proposed solution more except for the fact that I didn't have anyway of easily debugging my code.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4 fits great for your usage.
You can easily debug your programs if you have a Mac, then you just use the iPhone/iPad simulator that you get when downloading xCode / iPhone SDK.